# Returning the nth term of an inorder traversal of a binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I came up with this code but it requires a global variable `Rank`. Is there any way I can solve this problem without having to have a global variable?

```
int Rank = 0; 
public int inOrderTraversal(TreeNode node, int n){
    if(node==null)
        return 0;
    int x=inOrderTraversal(node.left,n);
    if(x!=0)return x;
    Rank++;
    if(n==Rank) return node.data;
    int y=inOrderTraversal(node.right,n);
    int c= x==0 ? y:x;
    return c;
}
```

I am just trying to return the nth term in an in-order traversal of a binary tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a `TraversalState` object down the recursion invocation chain, and store the number of nodes that you visited in a variable there:

```
class TraversalState {
    public int rank = 0;
}
...
public int inOrderTraversal(TreeNode node, int n, TraversalState ts){
    if(node==null)
        return 0;
    int x=inOrderTraversal(node.left,n, ts);
    ts.rank++;
    if(n==ts.rank) return node.data;
    int y=inOrderTraversal(node.right,n, ts);
    int c= x==0 ? y:x;
    return c;
}
```

Now your implementation is thread-safe, because it does not use "global" objects. Invoke it as follows:

```
int r = inOrderTraversal(myNode, targetN, new TraversalState());
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why are you initializing x twice and where does the y in `int c= x==0 ? y:x;`? This is a great question about design.

Comment: @ArjunPatel I copy-pasted the code from OP before the edit by Keeto (see edit history). The second `int x` should be `int y`. This is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive approach is easy to understand, but if your tree shape defies expectation, then you're at the mercy of maximum stack depth here, which is likely to be more limiting that heap memory consumed by an explicitly allocated stack structure. Hence, it's better to invest the time in building an iterative walker.

First, define the structure for the tree nodes themselves:

```
public final class TreeNode {
  public final int data;
  public final TreeNode left, right;


  public TreeNode(int data, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
    this.data = data;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }


  public TreeNode(int data) {
    this(data, null, null);
  }
}
```

We're going to want a way to react to events signaled during a depth-first walk through the tree. Returning true from these methods indicates that the visitor wishes for the walk to continue; returning false requests that the walk stop as soon as possible.

```
public abstract class Visitor {
  public boolean visitPre(TreeNode node) {
    return true;
  }


  public boolean visitMid(TreeNode node) {
    return true;
  }


  public boolean visitPost(TreeNode node) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now, define the iterative in-order walk algorithm:

```
final class InOrder {
  private InOrder() {}


  private static final class Breadcrumb {
    public final TreeNode node;
    public final boolean rightIsNext; // Not a great name.


    public Breadcrumb(TreeNode node, boolean rightIsNext) {
      this.node = node;
      this.rightIsNext = rightIsNext;
    }


    public static Breadcrumb goingLeft(TreeNode departingPoint) {
      return new Breadcrumb(departingPoint, true);
    }



    public static Breadcrumb goingRight(TreeNode departingPoint) {
      return new Breadcrumb(departingPoint, false);
    }
  }


  public static <T extends Visitor> T walk(TreeNode root, T visitor) {
    if (null == root ||
        null == visitor)
      throw new NullPointerException();
    final Deque<Breadcrumb> stack = new ArrayDeque<Breadcrumb>();
    if (!visitor.visitPre(root))
      return visitor;
    for (;;) {
      for (TreeNode left = root.left;
           null != left;
           root = left, left = root.left) {
        if (!visitor.visitPre(left))
          return visitor;
        stack.push(Breadcrumb.goingLeft(root));
      }
      if (!visitor.visitMid(root))
        return visitor;
      final TreeNode right = root.right;
      if (null != right) {
        if (!visitor.visitPre(right))
          return visitor;
        stack.push(Breadcrumb.goingRight(root));
        root = right;
      } else {
        if (!visitor.visitPost(root))
          return visitor;
        // Go back up the tree until we find a node with an unexplored right child.
        for (;;) {
          if (stack.isEmpty())
            return visitor;
          final Breadcrumb breadcrumb = stack.pop();
          if (breadcrumb.rightIsNext) {
            if (!visitor.visitMid(breadcrumb.node)) {
              return visitor;
            }
            if (null != breadcrumb.node.right) {
              if (!visitor.visitPre(breadcrumb.node.right))
                return visitor;
              stack.push(Breadcrumb.goingRight(breadcrumb.node));
              root = breadcrumb.node.right;
              break;
            }
          }
          if (!visitor.visitPost(breadcrumb.node))
            return visitor;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Exercise the `walk()` function on a sample tree:

```
     (1)
      |
    +-+-+
    |   |
   (2) (5)
    |
  +-+-+
  |   |
 (3)  -
  |
+-+-+
|   |
-  (4)
```

That is, there are five nodes, where both leaves with data 4 and 5 are right children.

```
final TreeNode root = new TreeNode(1,
                                   new TreeNode(2,
                                                new TreeNode(3,
                                                             null,
                                                             new TreeNode(4)),
                                                null),
                                   new TreeNode(5));
walk(root,
     new Visitor() {
       private final PrintStream ps = System.out;


       @Override
       public boolean visitPre(TreeNode node) {
         trace(node, "Pre");
         return true;
       }


       @Override
       public boolean visitMid(TreeNode node) {
         trace(node, "Mid");
         return true;
       }


       @Override
       public boolean visitPost(TreeNode node) {
         trace(node, "Post");
         return true;
       }


       private TreeNode trace(TreeNode node, String phase) {
         ps.print(phase);
         ps.print('(');
         ps.print(node.data);
         ps.println(')');
         return node;
       }
     });
```

This prints the following:

```
Pre(1)
Pre(2)
Pre(3)
Mid(3)
Pre(4)
Mid(4)
Post(4)
Post(3)
Mid(2)
Post(2)
Mid(1)
Pre(5)
Mid(5)
Post(5)
Post(1)
```

Now, you asked for a convenient way to find the nth node encountered during an in-order walk. We'll write a function called `findNthInOrder()`, where the parameter `n` designates zero as the first node encountered whose left subtree has already been explored, one designates the second, and so on:

```
private static TreeNode findNthInOrder(TreeNode root, final int n) {
  if (n < 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  return walk(root,
              new Visitor() {
                public TreeNode found = null;
                private int remaining = n + 1;

                @Override
                public boolean visitMid(TreeNode node) {
                  if (0 == --remaining) {
                    found = node;
                    return false;
                  }
                  return true;
                }
              }).found;
}
```

Calling this function on our sample tree yields the expected result:

```
final TreeNode nth = findNthInOrder(root, 3);
System.out.println(null != nth ? nth.data : "(none)");
```

This prints "1" to the console, which matches the previous tracing walk over the sample tree: the fourth (that is, the zero-based index 3, per the argument above) emitted "Mid" trace is for the root node bearing the `data` value of one.

In summary, consider building enough to formalize the concepts in play, so that you can write these specific queries more confidently atop a sound foundation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int inOrderTraversal(TreeNode node, AtomicInteger n){
    if(node == null) return 0;
    if(n == 0) return node.data;
    int leftVal = inOrderTraversal(node.left, n.decrementAndGet());
    if(n == 0) return node.data;
    int rightVal = inOrderTraversal(node.right,n.decrementAndGet());
    return leftVal == 0 ? rightVal : leftVal;
}
```

Or to use `MutuableInt` from [Apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableInt.html) instead of `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: I dont think this will work correctly, you are decrementing n in every function call. For example assume the tree has 10 nodes, each is to the left of its parent. n will be decrementing 10 times before even reaching the first node in the in-order traversal.

Comment: Right, it can be modified to only look if, the left/right is null and do not decrement the n (if (node.right == null) rightVal = 0)